# My ASP.NET Get all employees button is not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to get all employees in local host but somehow it is not working.

In html page i created buttons , where i click on button Request go to API controller i.e, EmployeeDataController.cs and this method is not working though. And that data which come from EmployeeDataController show in ShowData. When you get data from this API i.e, EmployeeDataController.cs and it return data type

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<h2>Index</h2>

<input type="button" value="Get All Employees" id="btn1" />

<br />

<input type="button" value="Clear" id="btn2" />

<br />

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Employee id" id="txt" />

<br />

<input type="button" value="Get All Employees By Id" id="btn3" />
<br />

<div id="ShowData">

</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $("#btn3").click(function () {
            var id = $("#txt").val();
            $.getJSON('/api/EmployeesData/' + id, function (responseData) {

                var item = "<h2>" + responseData + "</h2>";
                $(item).appendTo("ShowData");
            });

        });


        $("#btn2").click(function () {
            $("#ShowData").empty();
        });

        $("#btn1").click(function () {
            $.getJSON('/api/EmployeesData', function (responseData) {
                $.each(responseData, function (key, val) {
                    var item = "<h2>" + val + "</h2>";
                    $(item).appendTo("ShowData");
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

EmployeesDataController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace AspNetFirstWebApi.Controllers
{
   
 
    public class EmployeesDataController : ApiController
    {
        public string[] myEmployees = { "aditya", "Gyanu", "Rohan" };
        [HttpGet]
        public string[] GetEmployees()
        {
            return myEmployees;

        }
         public string GetEmployeesByIndex(int id)
        {
            return myEmployees[id];
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you forget to add the methods name in the getJSON? (GetEmployeesByIndex and GetEmployees)

Comment: Just a suggestion. In case when data we are excepting is not coming, try to do debug every step starting from calling API. It will help you alot

Answer (score 0):

As a variant.

Step 1:

```
$.getJSON('api/GetAllEmployees', function (responseData) {
    // CODE
});
```

Step 2:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/GetAllEmployees")]
public JsonResult GetEmployees()
{         
    return Json(myEmployees.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);       
}
```

Comment: I added but it is not working

Comment: $("#btn1").click(function () {
            $.getJSON('/api/GetAllEmployees', function (responseData) {
                $.each(responseData, function (key, val) {
                    var item = "<h2>" + val + "</h2>";
                    $(item).appendTo("ShowData");
                });
            });
        });

Comment: showing me this error:  jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2          GET https://localhost:44349/api/GetAllEmployees 404

Comment: So... Do you have valid WebApiConfig?

public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }

Comment: And check, you added "GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);" row in your Global.asax before RouteConfig row.

Comment: Now it is working